# Bash inside Vim not working properly

Tags: bash, vim, osx

In MacVim I'm using [Conque](https://code.google.com/p/conque/) to run bash commands inside Vim. I have a problem with the text navigation while using Conque.

If I'm at the end of a line of text and press down <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> I skip a word to the left, if I then press <kbd>←</kbd> the cursor moves back to after the word I skipped. How do I solve this?

Here you can see that I first move a few characters using <kbd>←</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> to move to the start of the word. Then when I press <kbd>←</kbd> I get back to where I were.

[image]

Comment: I actually don't get this question as written - what do you *want* to happen... or... what should the `alt` key be doing?

Comment: After I've pressed `Alt` `←` and then press `←`, the marker should continue before `Documents/` and not move back to where it was before I pressed `Alt` `←`. Just like how it works inside the regular terminal.

Comment: Actually you don't go back to where you were : You where at EOL-3 before _Alt_ _←_ then you go to EOL-4 after pressing _←_. So what I understand here is the  _Alt_ _←_ has not been "seen" either by bash or Conque. May be a problem with the escape sequence. I suggest you open a bug on Conque issue tracker.

Comment: On a side note try vimshell. And if you other plugins from shougo then vimshell works really well.

Comment: Why don't you open another tab in Terminal?

Comment: What version of Conque are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider filing a bug report. In the meantime, why not letting bash behave more vi-like? Issue `set -o vi` to use vi navigation in bash.

#### UPDATE

I've added this as an issue on the Conque website, here:

- [Issue 106: Bash inside Vim not working properly](https://code.google.com/p/conque/issues/detail?id=106).

Answer (score 1):

I thought this is what is documented as [Known bugs](https://code.google.com/p/conque/wiki/Usage#5.1_Known_bugs):

> - Conque only supports the extended ASCII character set for input, not utf-8. - VT100 escape sequence support is not complete.
> - Alt/Meta key support in Vim isn't great in general, and conque is no exception. Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> instead of <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> works in most cases.

I haven't used Conque, but just curious, does <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> help you navigate backwards and forwards words, respectively?